Longitudinal relaxation in NMR - a quantum description?
I'm currently reading Understanding NMR Spectroscopy by J. Keeler and in the section about longitudinal relaxation, he writes that (using $n_i$ for the population of state $i$)

the rate of change of $n_\alpha$ is $W_{\beta\to\alpha}n_\beta - W_{\alpha\to\beta}n_\alpha$ and similarly for $n_\beta$.
at equilibrium, the rate of change is zero, so $\frac {n_\alpha} {n_\beta} = \frac {W_{\beta\to\alpha}} {W_{\alpha\to\beta}}$.
however, QM predicts that $W_{\beta\to\alpha} = W_{\alpha\to\beta}$, which would suggest $n_\alpha = n_\beta$. This is clearly not in accord with the Boltzmann distribution.

He than says that the resolution is "that a more complete theory, where both the spins and the lattice are treated quantum mechanically". However, he gives no references for such a treatment. How would such an approach, which should yield the correct result, look like?
In other kinds of spectroscopy, the resolution there is that there is not only stimulated emission of radiation, but also spontaneous emission. The latter term then allows for the Boltzmann distribution to be satisfied. The rate of spontaneous emission can be computed from QED without reference to thermodynamic arguments. (Or it could be due to collisional relaxation in microwave and IR spectroscopy, I suppose.) However, in NMR, this "sponataneous emission" must mainly be caused by interactions with the lattice, right? So how would one go about calculating it without imposing the Boltzmann distribution in the first place?
